# How to make all the contents of a div appear if

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to make the contents of an entire div appear only if images are uploaded to Advanced Custom Fields. Here is what I'm working with but doesn't seem to be working.

```
<?php 

$image_l = get_field('accessories-image-large');
$image_s = get_field('accessories-image-small');
$size = 'full'; // (thumbnail, medium, large, full or custom size)

if( $image_l ) ?>

    <div class="widget-accessories-page">
    <div id="anchor-accessories-page"></div>
        <div class="widget-accessories-text" data-scroll>
            <h2>Title</h2>
            <p>Content</p>
        </div>
        <div class="wedding-product-accessories-large">              
            <?php {echo wp_get_attachment_image( $image_l, $size );} ?>
        </div>
        <div class="wedding-product-accessories-small">
            <?php {echo wp_get_attachment_image( $image_s, $size );} ?>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: try this one. change: 1.  `if( $image_l ) ?>` to `if( $image_l ): ?>`,  2. add after last closing `</div>` following: `<?php endif; ?>`, 3. remove `{` and `}` that wraps `echo` lines.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure of exactly what you are trying to achieve but here comes the possible solution to your question and they are based on the  curly braces { }

You should have in mind that if you are using an if-statement and you want more than one expression to be display every content then should be inside the curly braces like this:

```
if (condition) {
//content
}
```

In your specific case:

```
if( $image_l ) { ?> //adding curly braces here 

    <div class="widget-accessories-page">
    <div id="anchor-accessories-page"></div>
        <div class="widget-accessories-text" data-scroll>
            <h2>Title</h2>
            <p>Content</p>
        </div>
        <div class="wedding-product-accessories-large">              
            <?php echo wp_get_attachment_image( $image_l, $size ); ?> //removing curly braces here 
        </div>
        <div class="wedding-product-accessories-small">
            <?php echo wp_get_attachment_image( $image_s, $size ); ?> //removing curly braces here
        </div>
    </div>

<?php } ?> //adding Tcurly braces here
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking to do. Thank you so much for the explanation and demonstration!